# Any Eclipse autocompletion plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am not very satisfied with the behavior of Eclipse default autocompletion, unfortunatelly I've been unable to find any alternatives...

Did anyone find anything that could help me? Thank you...

Edit:

main issue is that eclipse doesn't select good candidates to be inserted, i tried to play with seting in advanced context assist preferencess but with minimal success.

Comment: What specifically are you dissatisfied with? Maybe it can be fixed through preferences?

Comment: It's been a while since I last use Eclipse(<troll>since NetBeans is a way better ;-) </troll>) but I remember there were options to modify autocompletion by default. That name was [code templates](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-add-your-own-code-template-in-eclipse.html)

Comment: Yes, it might be helpful if you explained why it is unsatisfactory.  Otherwise no one will actually know what the problem is you are trying to get solved.

Comment: agreed with Grooveek, use netbeans ... 
:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you describe what exactly is unsatisfying? Maybe by giving an example? Code Recommenders is working on various ways how to make code completion bit smarter. You may check

- http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#completion-engines and
- http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com/2011/05/subword-matching-completion-engine-for.html

which might be closely related. The subwords completion engine mentioned in the blog post has been started because of a post here from stackoverflow and a request in the code recommenders forum http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/209269/

You may consider to do the same (discuss your need at code recommenders forum)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin is what you are looking for: http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/